# How to run a Javascript function with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>   <meta charset="UTF-8">
>   <title>Quote generator</title>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
> </head>
> <body>
>   <h1 class = "quotes">Quotes</h1>
>   <img src ="https://placeimg.com/1100/300/nature" alt="nature" class="nature">
>   <div id = "output">
>
>   </div>
>   <script type ="text/javascript" src="js/student_report.js"></script>
>  <button onclick="print(blank)">Click me</button>
>  </body>
> </html
>
> > Blockquote
>
>
> function print(message) {   var output =
> document.getElementById('output');   output.innerHTML = message; }
> ```
>
> Blockquote

```
var blank = "";


function print(message) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = message;
}

function getQuote(array) {
  var quotes =  '<h2 class="quote">' + 'quote: ' + array.quote + '</h2>';
      quotes +=  '<p class="source">' + 'Soure: ' + array.source + '</p>';
      quotes += '<p class="year">' + 'year: ' + array.year + '</p>';
      quotes += '<p class="citation">' + 'citation: ' + array.citation + '</p>';
      return quotes
};





> 

var quotes = [{
  quote: "Great man", source: "jack mike", year: 1990, citation: "movie"},
              { quote: "Good stuff", source:"Mac jones", year: 1989, citation: "book"},
              { quote: "i love you", source: "mom and dad", year: 1993, citation: "love"},
              {quote: "you're a hero", source: "hero man", year: 2020, citation: "future"},
              {quote: "you're a wizard", source: "hero wizard", year: 2022, citation: "future4"},
               {quote: "you're a man", source: "hero man33", year: 2025, citation: "future3"},
               {quote: "you're a good person", source: "hero person", year: 2021, citation: "future2"},
               {quote: "you're a web developer", source: "hero developer", year: 2026, citation: "futures"}
              ];

var i = Math.round(Math.random() * quotes.length - 1);
blank += getQuote(quotes[i]);
print(blank);

function timer(){
 setInterval(print(blank), 3000);

}
timer();
```

So here I need to link that print function to the `onclick` so that when I click the button, it keeps printing out that message to the page in the same spot. It's a random quote generator code so what I want is it prints random quotes to the page when i click the button.

When I load the page everything loads as it should, but when I click the button NOTHING happens, just clicks and that's it.

IGNORE THE QUOTES TEXT its stupid dumb stuff long story, i would never use those quotes for a actual website

Sorry if I gave a bad description, as you can see I'm new to coding.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you post the javascript as well? Without seeing the js it's difficult to diagnose.

Comment: I added it just now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you're calling your function from the `onclick` attribute here:

```
<button onclick="print(blank)">Click me</button>
```

You would have seen an error in the JavaScript console saying this when you clicked the button:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: `blank`

If you want to print `blank`, you'll need quotation marks around the string you want to print. You can either use single quotation marks like so:

```
<button onclick="print('blank')">Click me</button>
```

Or you can use escaped double quotes like this:

```
<button onclick="print(\"blank\")">Click me</button>
```

Comment: i did that but it only printed the word "blank" to the page, i can link my JS file if that helps

Answer (score 1):

> The argument in the javascript file is called blank

Not sure what you mean there. If you're trying to pass a variable, it would have to be in global scope

**Edit:**

ok, it looks like the problem is that you're expecting `print(blank)` to change the quote displayed in the `output` div but `print` only changes the `innerHTML` of the div, it doesn't change `blank`, here's your code with a `console.log` in `print` to show that `print` is called.

```js
var blank = "";

function print(message) {
  console.log('here')
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = message;
}

function getQoute(array) {
  var qoutes =  '<h2 class="qoute">' + 'qoute: ' + array.qoute + '</h2>';
      qoutes +=  '<p class="source">' + 'Soure: ' + array.source + '</p>';
      qoutes += '<p class="year">' + 'year: ' + array.year + '</p>';
      qoutes += '<p class="citation">' + 'citation: ' + array.citation + '</p>';
      return qoutes
};

var qoutes = [{
  qoute: "Great man", source: "jack mike", year: 1990, citation: "movie"},
              { qoute: "Good stuff", source:"Mac jones", year: 1989, citation: "book"},
              { qoute: "i love you", source: "mom and dad", year: 1993, citation: "love"},
              {qoute: "you're a hero", source: "hero man", year: 2020, citation: "future"},
              {qoute: "you're a wizard", source: "hero wizard", year: 2022, citation: "future4"},
               {qoute: "you're a man", source: "hero man33", year: 2025, citation: "future3"},
               {qoute: "you're a good person", source: "hero person", year: 2021, citation: "future2"},
               {qoute: "you're a web developer", source: "hero developer", year: 2026, citation: "futures"}
              ];

var i = Math.round(Math.random() * qoutes.length - 1);
blank += getQoute(qoutes[i]);
print(blank);

function timer(){
 setInterval(print(blank), 3000);

}
timer();
```

```html
  <h1 class = "qoutes">Qoutes</h1>
  <img src ="https://placeimg.com/1100/300/nature" alt="nature" class="nature">
  <div id = "output">

  </div>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="js/student_report.js"></script>
 <button onclick="print(blank)">Click me</button>
```

Here's an update to your code that updates the quote and fixes a bunch of other stuff:

```js
const quotes = [
  { quote: "Great man", source: "jack mike", year: 1990, citation: "movie" },
  { quote: "Good stuff", source:"Mac jones", year: 1989, citation: "book" },
  { quote: "i love you", source: "mom and dad", year: 1993, citation: "love" },
  { quote: "you're a hero", source: "hero man", year: 2020, citation: "future" },
  { quote: "you're a wizard", source: "hero wizard", year: 2022, citation: "future4" },
  { quote: "you're a man", source: "hero man33", year: 2025, citation: "future3" },
  { quote: "you're a good person", source: "hero person", year: 2021, citation: "future2" },
  { quote: "you're a web developer", source: "hero developer", year: 2026, citation: "futures" }
];

function changeQuote() {
  const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getQuote(quotes[i]);
}

function getQuote({quote, source, year, citation}) {
  return `
    <h2 class="quote">quote: ${quote}</h2>
    <p class="source">soure: ${source}</p>
    <p class="year">year: ${year}</p>
    <p class="citation">citation: ${citation}</p>`;
};

changeQuote();
```

```html
  <h1 class = "quotes">Quotes</h1>
  <img src ="https://placeimg.com/1100/300/nature" alt="nature" class="nature">
  <div id = "output">

  </div>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="js/student_report.js"></script>
 <button onclick="changeQuote()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I added my JS script to the question just now.

Comment: OH MY GOSH thank you! I don't know Const yet, i'll learn that next in my course. But you pointed out the fact that my print didn't CHANGE anything, it just printed the same thing because the value in print was always the same, i needed to add to the function to make it so it would change, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is the `print()` function defined in the `student_report.js` file? If not, you have to also define the function in a `<script>` tag. And like said already, the "blank" variable has to be in a global scope.

Comment: How would I define it with a script tag?

Comment: I also added my JS script just now, to help with my question.

Answer (score 0):

replace below code instead of your existing button code

```
<button onclick="print('blank')">Click me</button>
```

when you send string to a function you have to use single/double quotes otherwise it will consider as js variable.